# CodeIgniter Model Function, getting synatx error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written one codeigniter model function, but getting syntax error in php 7.. will you please suggest me changes

Error near group by order by statements..

My Code Snippet:

```
function listing($searchText = '', $page, $segment)
    {
        $this->db->select('tr.*,group_concat(tg.groundname) as grplist ');
        $this->db->from('tb_tournament as tr ');
        $this->db->join('tournamentground as tg', 'tr.tournamentId=tg.tournamentId', 'left'); 

         $this->db->where('tr.is_deleted','0');
        if(!empty($searchText)) {
            $likeCriteria = "  (tr.organizerName  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.location  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.phone  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.email  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.level  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.gender  LIKE '%".$searchText."%')";
            $this->db->where($likeCriteria);
        }


         $this->db->group_by('tr.tournamentId');
         $this->db->order_by('tr.tournamentId', 'DESC'); 
         $this->db->limit($page, $segment);
         $query = $this->db->get();

         $result = $query->result();   
         //print"<pre>";
         //print_r($result);
         return $result;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show the complete error.

Comment: relevant image attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following logic in your query:

```
....
$this->db->or_like('tr.organizerName',$searchText);
$this->db->or_like('tr.location',$searchText);
....
....
```

It's done :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the SQL query being generated, not from PHP.

Instead of this big where condition you need need to use query grouping as outlined in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

```
$likeCriteria = "  (tr.organizerName  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.location  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.phone  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.email  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.level  LIKE '%".$searchText."%'
                            OR  tr.gender  LIKE '%".$searchText."%')";
$this->db->where($likeCriteria);
```

I haven't actually used codeIgnitor, but based on a quick look at the docs you probably need to replace the problematic block with something like this:

```
$this->db->group_start()
  ->or_where(tr.organizerName LIKE "%{$searchText}%")
  ->or_where(tr.location LIKE "%{$searchText}%")
  ->or_where(tr.phone LIKE "%{$searchText}%")
  ->or_where(tr.email LIKE "%{$searchText}%")
  ->or_where(tr.level LIKE "%{$searchText}%")
  ->or_where(tr.gender LIKE "%{$searchText}%")
  ->group_end();
```

It's worth noting that you could use some business logic to improve this query as well. For instance you could recognise when the search term is a phone number, or an email and restrict the query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution with query grouping

```
    function listing($searchText = '', $page, $segment)
        {
            $this->db->select('tr.*,group_concat(tg.groundname) as grplist ');
            $this->db->from('tb_tournament as tr ');
            $this->db->join('tournamentground as tg', 'tr.tournamentId=tg.tournamentId', 'left'); 

             $this->db->where('tr.is_deleted','0');
            if(!empty($searchText)) {
               $this->db->group_start()
                $this->db->like('tr.organizerName',$searchText);
                $this->db->or_like('tr.location',$searchText);
               $thsi->db->group_end()
            }


             $this->db->group_by('tr.tournamentId');
             $this->db->order_by('tr.tournamentId', 'DESC'); 
             $this->db->limit($page, $segment);
             $query = $this->db->get();

             $result = $query->result();   
             //print"<pre>";
             //print_r($result);
             return $result;
        }
```

Read more about query grouping here
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping